# Find Azure Search date without time part

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I can't find a way of getting a date from Azure Search using only the date.

The dates in the index are like: "2019-10-15T18:00:00Z","2019-10-22T18:00:00Z","2019-10-29T18:00:00Z"

If I try `StartDate/any(s: s eq 2019-10-15T18:00:00Z)` I get results
But with `StartDate/any(s: s eq 2019-10-15)` nothing comes up

I have tried usin the `date` OData function like so: `StartDate/any(s: date(s) eq 2019-10-15)` but I get an error 'Function 'date' is not supported'.

Is there any way to get dates without using the time part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of date literals in filters in Azure Search will no longer be supported starting in api-version 2019-05-06-Preview. This was an "accidental feature" that we never intended to support. The reason you don't get any results is because the implicit conversion from `Edm.Date` to `Edm.DateTimeOffset` assumes a time of midnight UTC, whereas the dates in your index are 6 PM UTC.

We recommend explicitly providing the time and offset (or Z for UTC) in filters to avoid this problem.

If you want Azure Search to natively support fields and filters of type `Edm.Date`, please vote for [this User Voice suggestion](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search/suggestions/14749479-support-edm-date-type).

Comment: But i need the times as well. The next question would be 'is it possible to search for times only'?

Comment: I'm confused. Are you storing dates, times, or both together? If it's both together, maybe what you want is a simple range filter?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that's actually the solution. The time issue I was having was a completely different story.

Answer (score 0):

> Date and time values represented in the OData V4 format: `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ` or `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fff[+&#124;-]HH:mm`. Precision of **DateTimeOffset** fields is limited to milliseconds. If you upload `DateTimeOffset` values with sub-millisecond precision, the value returned will be rounded up to milliseconds.

When you upload `DateTimeOffset` values with time zone information to your index, Azure Search normalizes these values to `UTC`.

Refer to [supported data types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/supported-data-types#edm-data-types-used-in-azure-search-indexes-and-documents) in Azure search.